# bootstrap Datetimepicker remove days of previous or next month from the current month

Tags: datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I would  like to remove days of previous or next month from current viewing month of datetimepicker calendar. to let you understand exactly what I mean I am  attaching the screen shot where I highlighted exactly what I need to remove

[image]

Comment: Which datetimepicker are you using?

Comment: its a bootstrap datetimepicker!

Comment: Which one? Can you link the docs page or share a live snippet/fiddle?

Comment: @VincenzoC we are using https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers datetimepicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```js
  $('#datetimepicker8').datetimepicker().on('show', function(e) {
  });
```

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table tr td.new { display: none; }
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table tr td.old { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker8'               class="datepicker">
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!  it  worked for me.  but is there any way of doing this with java script ?

Comment: You can do this with js also. Here we done this using css. The property settings done by using the above given css can also be done with js.

Comment: is there any property or method of datetimepicker so that we can do this with JS or Jquery not by CSS?

Comment: Here actually what we are doing is setting all next month td and previouse month td display property to none. Same thing can be don by with the help of js by finding the next month and previouse month td by using class name and setting its property to display none.